# WCF DataContracts : IList on server side and ObservableCollection on client side

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have two set of déclarations for my data contracts : one for server, one for client.

I generate my client datacontracts with t4 templates.

Is it possible to use an IList on server side and have it mapped to ObservableCollection on the client side ?

The reason for this is that on the client side I use WPF and ObservableCollection is just what I need.

**Question is : Does the *List* <=> *ObservableCollection* mapping will cause problems?**

Server :

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://mynamespace.com/myproduct", Name="MyContract")]
public class MyContract(){

  [DataMember]
  string Name {get;set;}

  [DataMember]
  List<string> MyList {get;set;}

}
```

client

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://mynamespace.com/myproduct", Name="MyContract")]
public partial class MyContract() : INotifyPropertyChanged{

  string _name;

  [DataMember]
  string Name {
    get {return _name;} 
    set { 
      if (Equals(value, _name)) return;
      _name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  [DataMember]
  ObservableCollection<string> MyList {get;set;}

}
```

If it's not available out of the box, how can I achieve this mapping ?

Comment: Have you already tried it? ;)

Comment: Yup. No errors yet but unsrue of side effects.